How to force nginx wait for PHP-FPM processing
I am running a website that allows to import large Excel file. It is using PHP-FPM and Nginx. Nginx response 504 Gateway Time-out after exactly 60s. I have read many questions and try to change the configuration as following:
# Nginx
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s;
proxy_read_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

# PHP
request_terminate_timeout = 600s;
max_execution_time = 600s;

I need to ask Nginx response after 5 minutes or PHP-FPM finish processing the file. But it always response after 60 seconds and return 504 Gateway Time-out. I've tried to find where the configuration of PHP or Nginx involve to 60 seconds but nothing found.
Any idea?

Have you considered making it an asynchronous request, which can spend time running in the background and have another request checking for a marker if the first one has finished? That would also be more userfriendly.

did you try to set the timeout and execution time values in the fpm pool's config file?

Those proxy_..._timeout directives has nothing to do with the PHP-FPM backend; only fastcgi_..._timeout directives matters. What you can do is to check actual max_execution_time parameter value using phpinfo() function to be sure some other PHP or FPM pool configuration file does not overwrite it.

Try to

Restart nginx and fpm services after config changes
Change the right php config file (same address in phpinfo())

Also, please try to check the nginx and php log files to see which one is not working fine.
